# element.animate, applying style changes after the animation is finished

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am running a simple native element.animate:

```
element.animate([{
        transform: "translate(0px, 0)"
    }, {
        transform: "translate(200px, 0)"
    }], {
        duration: 1000,
        iterations: 1,
        delay: 0,
        easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)',
        direction: 'normal',
        fill: 'both'
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tox47k28/

The problem is that after the animation ends I can not set any transform styles to that element. The transform propriety seems frozen.

The only way to "unfroze" that propriety would be to call .cancel() on that animation, but then, the element reverts to its initial state.

**UPDATE 29 OCT 2014**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f27hpnjL/1/

You can nolonger "unfreeze" an animation with "fill: both". If you want to manipulate the styles afterwards you need to "fill: backwards":

```
element.animate([{
        transform: "translate(0px, 0)"
    }, {
        transform: "translate(200px, 0)"
    }], {
        duration: 1000,
        iterations: 1,
        delay: 0,
        easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)',
        direction: 'normal',
        fill: 'backwards' // Use this inorder to manipulate the style attribute after animation end

}).onfinish = function(e){

    //    I wish I had a refference to my keyframes here!!!
    //    Reset the last keyFrame
    element.style.webkitTransform = "translate(200px, 0)";
    //    Cancel the animation
    this.cancel();
}
```

Comment: You can use [GroupEffect](http://danielcwilson.com/blog/2015/09/animations-part-4/) or [SequenceEffect](http://danielcwilson.com/blog/2015/09/animations-part-4/) to further transform your element/s. This only if your transform is not dictated by mouse position (eg. drag).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you just use this?

```
var animation = element.animate([{
        transform: "translate(0px, 0)"
    }, {
        transform: "translate(200px, 0)"
    }], {
        duration: 1000,
        iterations: 1,
        delay: 0,
        easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)',
        direction: 'normal',
        fill: 'both'
}); 
animation.onfinish = function () {
     animation.cancel();
     element.style.transform = "translate(400px, 0)"    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tox47k28/2/

Comment: CSS transforms were unprefixed Chrome 36. http://www.chromestatus.com/features/6437640580628480

Comment: Seems to work without the `setTimeout`. Just need to call `animation.cancel()` first.

Comment: ah, sorry, I tried something else first. Forgot to remove the timeout :-) updated

Comment: Yes, that was my first approach but I looks like a hack. Was hoping for else without having to call cancel(). In this case you have to set all proprieties that were animated.